# Read User profile relative files on dotnet core

Tags: .net-core

How does one correctly deal with file paths using dotnet core in a platform agnostic way? i.e. I am using a Mac and when trying to open a file relative to my user profile

```
var file="~/Downloads/example.zip";
var fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(file);
```

returns

```
/Users/Me/Projects/Test/Test/~/Downloads/example.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1

Use `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%HOME%")` to get the equivalent of `~`. So something like

```
var file = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%HOME%/Downloads/example.zip");
```

## Option 2

Use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME")`:

```
var file = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") + "/Downloads/example.zip");
```

## Option 3:

Use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)`:

```
var file = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) ....
```